# Cache PDF file in browser based on url

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, caching, browser-cache

I am using http://pdfobject.com/ to embed PDF files inside a `div`. Users use several buttons to save metadata in a database for the PDF file. Every time users click on a button the PDF file is retrieved from the server which makes the system slow.

Is there a way to cache the PDF so that it loads only once. There are many PDF files which has different URL's so the best way is cache PDF files based on their URL. How can I cache PDF files in browser based on their URL?